# Cannot connect to windows share

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

I've been going through and pouring over resource for the past few hours and I cannot get my box to connect to my friends network drive.

My friend doesn't use linux, but he's setup the network share like this:
`DPR:\\name\images` and he's given me the username and password which I've verified is correct. It is located on `192.168.0.2`

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=***,password=*** //name/images /media/name/`

`sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.2/name/images /media/name/ -o credentials=~/name.credentials` (I've confirmed that `~/name.credentials` does have the correct credentials as well)

Regardless of what I attempt I get

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's probably really simple and stupid. Thanks to any/all in advance.

EDIT: I don't know if this helps, but I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use a file-manager like `nautilus` or `thunar`.

Hit Ctrl+L and use

> smb://user@name/images

and type in the password when prompted.